# how do I make erlang connect with mysql?

Tags: mysql, database, erlang

I'm trying to use odbc to connect some erlang code to a mysql server.

I've started up the odbc manager with odbc:start().

But I simply cant get the connect call working,

My connect call looks like this:

> odbc:connect("server=localhost;port=3306;Uid=root",[]).

the only thing I have to work with is the error:

> {error,"No SQL-driver information available. Connection to database failed."}

If someone could help me I would be most grateful.

/ Martin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've heard good things about [erlang-mysql-driver](https://github.com/dizzyd/erlang-mysql-driver) from @dizzyd.

Comment: I'm considering this as a good answer, The driver worked out of the box and is pretty intuitive to use.

Answer (score 1):

You don't configure a driver in your DSN. The ODBC system won#t know which to use. Try this:

```
odbc:connect("driver=MySQL;server=localhost;port=3306;Uid=root",[]).
```

Comment: it gives back the same error.`{error,"No SQL-driver information available. Connection to database failed."}` I'm starting to think if its a 'not able to see the driver lib' sorta error.. MySql installed it self in a strange way on my Mac...

Answer (score 1):

I heard that exists good non-odbc driver for mysql (but didn`t use it, because have other db). I strongly recommend you to use it, because ODBC application from erlang distribution has many unuseable features and bad docs. You can read my questions here, it mostly related to odbc driver.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is some problem with configuring a driver in your DSN.

Try this,

In your odbc.ini file which is in /etc directory

write this following configuration

```
[myodbc1]
Driver       = /usr/lib/odbc/libmyodbc.so
Description  = MySQL ODBC 2.50 Driver DSN
Server       = localhost
Port         =
User         = <Mysql username>
Password     = <Mysql password>
Database     = <database name>
Option       = 3
Socket       =
```

And in your code write the following

```
Connecting_Str="DSN=myodbc1"
odbc:connect(Connecting_Str,[])
```

And tell what you get.

.